# Good Online SVN

Tags: svn

We are planning a project in PHP and our locations are different , We are working in SVN, So that please any one suggest us a good online SVN or SVN over FTP .

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about mercurial and bitbucket? ps: what do you mean by saying `online SVN or SVN over FTP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you guys have a server with ssh access, you could also do svn over ssh.

```
# server
$ svnadmin create /home/username/svn/myproject

# your laptop / pc / mac
$ svn import yourproject svn+ssh://username@hostname/home/username/svn/myproject
```

So all commands will go through `svn+ssh` protocol, but once you checkout from remote server, you can do `svn commit`, `svn update` etc as per normal (no need to specify full path)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [project on google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/createProject)
They provide a svn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. One more doubt.. if I created a proj in google code is that available for every one / public to download ?

Comment: Yes indeed the code is available for everyone. If you want a non open source svn you can check out https://www.assembla.com/. But there are restrictions on the number of member in the free plan...

Comment: Is it online SVN or offline ? We only need 2 users .. Thanks for the reply ...

Comment: Here is the free plan with every information you'll need https://www.assembla.com/catalog/tag/Free?type=private

Answer (score 1):

I host my own subversion server, but I have used https://github.com/ before. It's very trusted.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a project on the [google code](http://code.google.com/) and use the svn service by google code. However, if you use google code, your project must be an open source project.